# Hit a URL with Jdk1.6 and Jdk1.7 Keystores and SSL Certificates

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, java-6

I am creating a program to hit https url and get response.
I was able to hit through jdk1.6 with required certificate in jdk1.6 keystores.
To use it with jdk1.7, I have copied cacert (keystore) file of 1.6 in jdk1.7.
Even though I am not able to hit the same url using jdk1.7.
What should I do now , please suggest ...

Comment: You need to be much less vague. **HOW** do you "hit" the URL? URL.openConnection()? HttpClient? SSLSocket? something else? Do you specify particular protocols/versions and/or ciphers? Is this on the same machine or different machines? Are you running manually (e.g. shell) or in some environment like an appserver or an IDE? **WHAT** happens? If you get an exception and stacktrace, post them (use "code" markdown where appropriate). If you get an HTTP error, or invalid response, show it. Do you have or if necessary can you get network traces?

Comment: Hi dave_thompson_085. Thanks for suggestions. I have got an answer. I have installed all certificate in jdk1.7 which are exists in jdk1.6 and run the program. It is working fine as expected.